# Cross-Axis Length Ignores Margins

Tags: css, flexbox

One really cool thing about flexbox is that, if there is room, the flex items' margins are included in the width of the flex container, even if I tell it to take up the whole space. For example, if I have an 100px-wide flex container, and give it a single child that takes up its whole width, then give that child 10px margins on both sides, the child actually becomes 80px wide, as the container allows the child to be completely encapsulated, including the margins. This ignores concerns about overflow, which can be worked around quite easily (`min-width: 0;` usually handles this).

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

flex-item {
  display: block;
  background-color: darkgray;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

However, this trick does not seem to extend to the cross-axis (`height` normally, `width` with `flex-direction: column`). If I now give my flex item 10px margins on the top and bottom, instead of the left & right, and give it the whole height instead of the whole width like before, it starts to extend past the bottom edge of the container. Why is that?

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

flex-item {
  display: block;
  background-color: darkgray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

I have seen this behavior on Google Chrome as well as Firefox. It is probably also he case on Internet Explorer/Edge, but I have not had the ability to test.

**Why does the flex item stay inside margins on the main axis, but not on the cross axis?**

Comment: red vs. green is hard to look at for me

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of a designer. How is green/orange?

Comment: Better! Thx for updating : ) Some useful color tools are listed on https://github.com/ryanve/a11y#accessible-colors such as https://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/ where you can aim for 4.5+ contrast ratio

Comment: The lea verou one looks like it is for background & text color. Is it for 2 background colors, as well?

Comment: Yeah I think the same idea applies. In particular many people have issues with red-green color blindness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Red.E2.80.93green_color_blindness

Comment: OK, sorry. As I said, I am not a designer, but that red/green was hard to look at for me, too. Too bright. I will certainly use that leaverou tool at home. At work, I don't have to be a designer, too.

Comment: Nice—happy devsigning and coding then : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in the direction flex is set, and since `flex-grow`'s default is 0, it is not allowed to grow, but it is allowed to shrink, (`flex-shrink` default is `1`), so it does.

Here is the same test using column direction, where you will get the reverse behavior.

Your first sample, but with column direction

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

flex-item {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

---

Your second sample, but with column direction

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}
flex-item {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

If you want a similar behavior, where the flex item shrinks and doesn't overflow its parent, simply remove the given width/height

Sample for row direction

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
}

flex-item {
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

Sample for column direction

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}

flex-item {
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

Comment: Thank you! I know about `flex-direction`, and actually mentioned it in my question. I always ignored the effects of `flex-shrink`/`flex-grow`, except to solve specific problems, generally browser bugs, like [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) 1, 6 & 12. Is there any way to emulate these properties in the cross direction?

Comment: @trysis If you, in this case, add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the flex item they will behave the same and overflow their parent in both axis

Comment: I mean the opposite situation. How do I allow the shrinking on both axes?

Comment: @trysis does using `flex-basis` instead of width and height help? `flex-basis` is aware of the `flex-direction`

Comment: @ryanve Nope, he wants to achieve the same behavior in the none direction, so flex-basis won't work.

Comment: @trysis Since margin's always adds to a given width or height, you need to do `width: calc(100% - 20px);`, resp. `height: calc(100% - 20px);` .... or you simply remove the set width/height ... and I can't say exactly how this behave cross browser, you need to check which one works, either should work though

Comment: Your first solution is an OK solution, usually, though it does require some duplication. Your second solution is often better, as it is shorter as it cuts out the `height: 100%`. Is there a third solution for lesser percentages? For example, `width: 33%; margin: 10px`? This requires a little more duplication, and starts to remind me of Bootstrap's grid system.

Comment: @trysis May I ask what you want to achieve with `width: 33%; margin: 10px;`?

Comment: Something like Bootstrap's grid system, with no margins on the outside. It's kind of hard to explain in a comment. I don't have much faith that I will find anything, or at least anything with much browser support, but that was one of many situations that inspired this question.

Comment: @trysis Then I recommend you skip margin's and use padding's to create the gutter between your grid items. May I also ask you to accept the answer that solve your original question? ... And if you have additional question, feel free to post yet another question with extended requirements, as I'm sure we can help you more, one question at a time :)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I won't bother with another question, because as I said I am not optimistic. Your answer explains reasoning and is enough for most cases, thank you.

Comment: @trysis Ask as many questions you need, just post them one-by-one :)

Comment: Well, that was meant to be part of this question. I will think about asking another question, just need to figure out how to put it. Thank you for the encouragement.

Comment: After further reflection (and an entire unreleased question) your answer is enough for me for pretty much all flex-y situations I find myself in. It also clarifies what was actually going on, which was perhaps more important. If I find or remember a specific situation where it is not enough, I will ask another question. Thank you again.

Comment: @trysis That sounds perfect, and glad to be able to help

Answer (score 1):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property).

This means that flex items will shrink when necessary to avoid overflowing the container.

The `flex-shrink` property (along with `flex-grow`, `flex-basis` and `flex`) works only on the main axis. That's why you see a difference in your width vs. height examples.

When you add top and bottom margins to a flex item in a row-direction container, the `flex-shrink: 1` feature does not apply (because you're now in the cross axis), so the item will not shrink to accommodate the added margins.

If you disable `flex-shrink`, your flex item with horizontal margins will overflow the container:

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

flex-item {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item></flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will respect the margins when you define the flexbox as a column and remove the width: 100% for the child.

```css
flex-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

flex-item {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it to include the margin in the *cross* direction. Changing to `flex-flow: column` makes the height the main axis.

Comment: Code adjusted. Only height: 100% removed.

Comment: I clarified the intent of my question. I want to know why `width: 100%` on the child excludes the margins, but `height: 100%` does not. And yes, this still ignores the effects of `flex-direction`/`flex-flow`.